Services in child module are shared with parent module's component
I've an angular applicatoin with the following module structure:
Data module
     --> Data component
     --> Data service
List module
  --> imports Data module
   --> List component
          --> which calls Data component
   --> Parent List component
          --> which in turn calls List component


Data services works fine when I am using List component.
When I use Parent List component, it renders List component which in turn renders Data component, but Data service is shared and same as step 1.

It should've created separate instance of Data service.
Any suggestions on what I am missing would be appreciated.
Thanks.

If you need another service instance, you should try providing the service at the component level instead. You should try adding it to the providers array of the ListComponent.

You can add in providers array of a Component or Module the service (or using provideIn in the own service). When use as provider it's a new instance.

The scope of your service depends on how and where you are provinding it.
If you've declared your service as providedIn: 'root', then only one global instance of your service will be created and shared accros all modules/component where the service is provided.
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
class DataService {
    // Unique DataService shared accross modules
}

But you can restrict the scope of a service by either changing the value of providedIn link to documentation.
Or by removing it all together which allows you to provide it at the component level, consider the following snippet :
// We declare the service as injectable without providedIn
@Injectable()
class DataService {
    // The service will do nothing on its own and will never be instantiated
    // If we don't provide it in any component
}

We can then provide it in a component, which will cause the service to be instanciated when the component is created :
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  template: ``,
  styleUrl: ``,
  providers: [
    DataService
  ]
})
export class ListComponent {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-list',
  template: `<app-list></app-list>`,
  styleUrl: ``,
})
export class ParentListComponent {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
}

The DataService will now only be instancied when a ListComponent is created, and the instance will be destroyed when the associated ListComponent is destroyed.
